# Loop through fields in rdlc report

Tags: field, rdlc

I have an Rdlc report
In this report I have a field which takes its values by this expression

```
(Round(((First(Fields!Occurs.Value) / First(Fields!TotalDistance.Value))* 10000),2)
```

but in some cases (TotalDistance.Value) = 0  so the previous expression returns Infinity,
So I need to get the next record in case of that field equals 0 , 
If also next field equals 0 , I want to get the next one

I looked for way of getting next record but didn't find
I only found (First , Last) methods, 
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

instead of using First or Last if you don't care which record as long as it isn't 0 then couldn't you use an aggregate function. ex:

```
(Round(((First(Fields!Occurs.Value) / MAX(Fields!TotalDistance.Value))* 10000),2)
```

you could use Max, Min or Avg to get a value. I am unaware of any way within the rdlc to loop through the records like you are asking.

Another completely different way could be to load the data into a datatable then add a column to contain the calculated value and use some code to calculate the values before being passed to the report.

Comment: I made as you suggested, 
I Calculated values before passing them to the report,
Thanks